# activex controls vs forms control in excel

Tags: combobox, excel, excel-2007, vba

I have some activex as well as forms control (drop downs for testing purpose) on my excel 2007 worksheet. I have binded the data using the code below :

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If ComboBox1.Value = 1 Then
        ComboBox2.List = Array("a", "b", "c")
        ComboBox2.Value = ComboBox2.List(0)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = 2 Then
        ComboBox2.List = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
        ComboBox2.Value = ComboBox2.List(0)        
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ComboBox1.List = Array(1, 2)  
    ComboBox3.List = Array("Delhi", "Kolkata")
    ComboBox3.Value = ComboBox3.List(0)
    ComboBox4.List = Array("Delhi6", "Kolkata71")
    ComboBox4.Value = ComboBox4.List(0)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.List = Array(1, 2)
End Sub
```

But when I reopen my worksheet, the comboboxes are opening in the state in which they were 
closed and no data remains in the dropdown. Please advise as to which event I'm missing to fire??

Thanks in advance...

Comment: 1) Why are you using `UserForm_Initialize` if the controls are on the worksheet? 2) Are the controls on the 1st sheet? 3) Is the Combobox aan ActiveX Control or For Control?

Comment: Hi Sid, The controls are on sheet1. ComboBox1 and 2 are forms control while 3,4 are activex....

Comment: Thanks for answering Q2 and Q3. That's leaves with Q1. :)

Comment: oops...my mistake....to that I would say..i was just playing around as i aint an expert in excel...i thought that may be the event...

Comment: Premanshu, can I see your excel file? If yes, you can upload it in wikisend.com and share the link here...

Comment: Hi Siddharth, pls find the link here http://wikisend.com/download/723486/Book1.xlsm

Comment: I see that you have already got your answer so I guess there is no need for me to see the workbook?

Comment: Well, u r always welcome to check..... :) Though the forms control and activex control i m reading from msexcel to differenciate

Answer (score 0):

I found out (taking help from a friend of mine) the mistake that I was making... UserForm_Initialize function I was using in my sheet should not be used at all. Secondly Worksheet_Activate would not be used as well.

The required functon is

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Sheets("Print_Sheet").ComboBox1.List = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
Sheets("Print_Sheet").ComboBox3.List = Array("Delhi", "Kolkata")
Sheets("Print_Sheet").ComboBox3.Value = ComboBox3.List(0)
Sheets("Print_Sheet").ComboBox4.List = Array("Delhi6", "Kolkata71")
Sheets("Print_Sheet").ComboBox4.Value = ComboBox4.List(0)
End Sub
```

This would be used in ThisWorkbook under Microsoft Excel Objects.
Now the combos are populated properly.